# Use math operators on generic variables in a generic Java class

Tags: java, generics, math

I'm trying to write some code that will allow me to perform basic math operations on a "T extends Number" object instance. It needs to be able to handle any number type that is a subclass of `Number`.
I know some of the types under `Number` have `.add()` methods built in, and some even have `.multiply()` methods. I need to be able to multiply two generic variables of any possible type. I've searched and searched and haven't been able to come up with a clear answer of any kind.

```
public class Circle<T extends Number> {

private T center;
private T radius;
private T area;

// constructor and other various mutator methods here....

/**
  The getArea method returns a Circle
  object's area.
  @return The product of Pi time Radius squared.
*/
public Number getArea() {
    return  3.14 * (circle.getRadius()) * (circle.getRadius());      
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Generics are the most difficult thing I've encountered in learning Java. I don't mind doing the leg work because I learn better that way, so even a strong point in the right direction would be very helpful.

Comment: You should probably be using `Math.PI` rather than your literal `3.14`.

Comment: This won't work that way. As T extends Number, you are only allowed to call methods of the class Number.

Answer (score 4):

What you will need to do is use the double value of the `Number`.  However, this means that you cannot return the `Number` type.

```
public double getArea()
{
    return  3.14 * 
            (circle.getRadius().doubleValue()) * 
            (circle.getRadius().doubleValue());      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java does not allow operators to be called on classes (so no +, -, *, /) you have to do the math as a primitive (I was going to show the code... but jjnguy beat me to it :-).